# Echo of data in UART through interrupts in LM3S811 Qemu Simulation

Tags: arm, microcontroller, cortex-m, microprocessors

I am trying to transmit and receive characters in UART through interrupts in LM3S811 using Qemu Simulation. I wrote this code with the help of this https://www.electronicwings.com/arm7/lpc2148-uart0. I am not sure whether it is correct and it does not work. Could someone suggest how to get the task done.

startup code :

```
.thumb
.global start
start:
.word 0x20001000
.word main
```

flash.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x00010000
    SRAM (rxw)  : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x00002000
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text : {
        *(.vectors);
        *(.text);
        etext = .;
    } > FLASH

    .rodata : {
        *(.rodata);
    } > FLASH

    .data : {
        sdata = .;
        *(.data);
        edata = .;
    } > SRAM AT > FLASH

    .bss: {
        sbss = .;
        *(.bss);
        ebss = .;
    }  > SRAM
    
}
```

main.c

```
#define  UARTDR (*((volatile unsigned int *) 0x4000C000))  // Data register for UART...
#define UARTIFLS (*((volatile unsigned int *) 0x40000034)) // Interrupt identification register...
#define  UARTFR (*((volatile unsigned int *) 0x4000C018))  // Register which holds the status of the FIFO...
char rx;

_irq void UART0_Inerrupt(void)
{
    int iir_value;
    iir_value = UARTIFLS  // Interrupt Identification register...

    if (iir_value & 0x00) {  // If interrupt is received, i.e data is present... 
        rx = UARTDR; 
    }
    UARTDR = rx; // Write to data register for writing to transmit FIFO...
    while ( (UARTFR & 0x20) == 1) continue; 
}

int main(void)
{
    NVICVectAddr0 = (unsigned) UART0_Inerrupt;
    while(1);
}
``
```

Comment: One would hope the sim is honoring the flash being a flash (read only for purposes of simulation), so you need to at compile time set the vector, not at runtime.  plus you are missing a uart init, etc in this code. uart interrupts are not the first ones you would want to do in real code, nor even in this sim so I wont to and write this code for you this time.

Comment: interrupts are advanced, lots more learning to do before you get there, start with something simpler like (events) systick, svc/swi, then ones (interrupts) that go through an interrupt controller, using a timer perhaps.  always start with polling, use the uart or some other debug solution to see the register values as you set up the resource, and see the interrupts happen (in the peripheral, but block them or dont enable them into the core until you fully understand how to control them).

Comment: then see the interrupts enter the core interrupt controller (if present/enabled) and poll through that before enabling it to actually interrupt the processor.